# Ubuntu League of Legends very slow

Tags: nvidia, java, minecraft

I have an problem fixing everything I want to have on Linux.
Like Minecraft, League of Legends, Origin, Curse.

Minecraft and League of Legends are already on my computer.
So i just started League of Legends and it started with Medium video settings and lagged so hard I couldn't even play.

**40 FPS on slowest settings.
07 FPS on highest settings.**

An also Minecraft has big frame drops.

My specs:

> Intel Core i7-3630QM CPU / 2.0 GHZ / 4 CORES, 8 THREADS. nVIDIA
> Geforce GT 650M 2GB. 6 GB Ram.

On Windows everything runs smoothly.

I will really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, League of Legends has no linux version, so I will assume you are using WINE. If you are not, please go onto my next suggestion.

However, ***IF YOU ARE USING WINE***, you might want to check out PlayOnLinux. This is a wrapper for people who are less experienced with Linux distributions (like Ubuntu) and it allows for easily managing multiple WINE prefixes. That being said, most likely if you followed the first result on google to install League of Legends on linux, you are using a seriously outdated version. I recommend following a very recent guide and for sure using a version of WINE such as 1.7 or above. You also might want to check out a special patch called CSMT. PlayonLinux has certain patched versions that are available. To install PlayOnLinux, you will have to go to this website [(CLICK HERE)](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html) and scroll down until you see the "Ubuntu" tab. You will then be instructed how to install PlayOnLinux.

***IF YOU HAVE NOT MODIFIED YOUR NVIDIA DRIVERS*** you will need to make a check. Go to your settings and go to the drivers/updates section. After you get there, you will need to look for a tab that says drivers and look to see what Nvidia driver you are using. Chances are, you are using NOUVEAU drivers which are Open-Source. At the moment, these are not as fast as the Nvidia drivers you can get through Ubuntu's repository and not even close to as fast as those in the Xorg-Edgers PPA. If you see that NOUVEAU drivers are selected, this is also a large reason your performance may be poor. You can select another driver such as Nvidia 331 or Nvidia 334. Also, if you'd like, you can check out Xorg-Edgers. To get their repository AND get Nvidia 337 drivers, run the following command in your terminal window:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-337
```

Then, save all of your work and reboot your computer. ***MAKE SURE YOU COPY THE ENTIRE CODE ENTERED ABOVE AND*** then open up a terminal window (using Alt+T) and then right click and select paste. Then hit enter and the installation process will begin. I will try to post pictures in a few hours to show you how to get up and running as well.

Please comment if you've tried BOTH of these and nothing worked so I will try to troubleshoot the problem. Off the top of my head, these are the most common problems people face. Good luck!